# After exiting app, how to go back to the exact same screen where I left off?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is there a quick and easy way to have the app go back to the same screen after I put it in background mode?

I know there are frameworks just for this stuff, but has anyone done it without much sweat?

Thanks

Comment: note: if you are using simulator and always click "build and run" in xcode, the app gets launched from the beginning each time which means xcode first terminates you running app, reinstalls it and launches it again. so no multi-tasking here.

Use the springboard to open your app (in simulator) to get the multitasking feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app delegate, add a line to the `applicationDidenterBackground:` method that stores the current page via NSUserDefaults.

Then in the `applicationWillEnterForeground:` method, load up that saved value and restore the page.

Answer (score 1):

Multitasking should enable this, while a device has enough memory to keep your app open. Otherwise how about using [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to store a string reference to your view?

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 5.1, there is no quick and easy way.

Comment: Did something new happen to remove or change backgrounding? I would have thought this supports it fine.

Comment: I assumed he actually cares about restoring state when the app has exited and is relaunched, since you don't need to do anything to restore state when the app comes back to the foreground from the background.

Comment: From the question... `after I put it in background mode`

Comment: From the title... “After exiting app”. Also, once an app is in the background, the system may kill it at any time to free up system resources.  If you don't save your state on entering the background, you may lose it.  And iOS 5.1 has no “quick and easy” “without much sweat” system to save complex application state.

Comment: I would have made this answer a comment then. There isn't enough fleshing out to warrant making it an answer.